# How can calling a function with an alias name or attribute name?

Tags: c#

I have a method like this.

```
        [CodeName("Bar")]
        public bool IsWidow(Guid applicantId)
```

And I want to call this method with a code that I have as an attribute above this function.
something like this
bar();

How it is possible to call the `IsWidow()` method when I call `bar()` method?

Comment: Since you can only access attribute information via reflection you will have to emit your `bar` method that way. Which seems like a serious overkill, why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem. What are you trying to achieve that led to this solution?

Comment: not really sure what you're doing here. BUt to call IsWidow when bar is called you just do this:  bar() { IsWidow(); }

Comment: @matthew See , I have some codes that related to some function, one to one relationship.
I need to call these functions with these codes that associate with them.

Comment: Why not just create a new method `Bar` which simply calls `IsWidow`?

Comment: @Achdari, Becuse there are too many methods and in this case I need to call a method with a code .

Comment: Where does the bar method come from? Is it inside the same class? Why can't you directly call bar from inside IsWidow?

Comment: And why do you not rename `IsWidow` to `Bar`? Also how dou you want to call `Bar`?

Comment: @Ackdari,In this exaple they are generated and I can't do like what you said.

Comment: If you really want to create a new method at runtime, based on an attribute, you need to use either `System.Reflection.Emit` (see e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/emitting-dynamic-methods-and-assemblies) or in some cases you can use `System.Linq.Expressions` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netcore-3.1#examples) - either way does however involve a fair bit of work and I still don't understand why you need it

Comment: @amirkian if they're generated, then can you also generate: `partial class WhateverSameName { public bool bar(Guid applicantId) => IsWidow(applicantId); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here a working Example:**
Here the example class

```
public class myClass
{
    [myAtt("Bar")]
    public void Mehtod1(string someText, int ID)
    {
        //Inside method one
    }

    [myAtt("someOtherText")]
    public void Mehtod2()
    {
        //Inside method 2
    }


    public class myAtt : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public myAtt(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

---

And here the working example: (Look at example 1. Example one is exactly what you are looking for)

---

```
public void DoWork()
    {
        myClass myClassObj = new myClass(); //Create an object of your class

        /*      Main Example    */
        //This is what you are looking for

        var allMethods2 = myClassObj.GetType().GetMethods(); //Get all methods in the class
        foreach (var method in allMethods2) //loop
        {
            var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(false); //custom attributes
            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                var attribute =
                    attributes.FirstOrDefault(att => att is myClass.myAtt); //Get the attribute you are looking for
                if (attribute != null && ((myClass.myAtt)attribute).Name == "Bar") //check null & check if the 'inside' of the attribute is correct
                {
                    var parameters = method.GetParameters();
                    var objToPass = new List<object>();
                    foreach (var parameterInfo in parameters) //Loop through method params
                    {
                        var toAdd = new object(); //Object to pass after the loop
                        if (parameterInfo.ParameterType == typeof(string))
                        {
                            //Param is string
                            switch (parameterInfo.Name)
                            {
                                case "someText":
                                    toAdd = "Some text to add";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    //Log?
                                    toAdd = "Don't know the attribute...";
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (parameterInfo.ParameterType == typeof(int))
                        {
                            //Param is int
                            switch (parameterInfo.Name)
                            {
                                case "ID": //Param is an ID
                                    toAdd = 1; //Some ID
                                    break;
                                case "numberFromOneToTen": //Param is a number from 1 - 10
                                    var random = new Random();
                                    toAdd = random.Next(1, 10);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    //Log?
                                    toAdd = -9999; //e.g an error code
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        objToPass.Add(toAdd); //Add object to pass to the list 

                    }


                    method.Invoke(myClassObj, objToPass.ToArray()); //Invoke the method
                    
                }
            }
        }

        


        /*  Second Example  */

        //In this case below you are not looking for the inside of the attribute
        var allMehtods = myClassObj.GetType().GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(myClass.myAtt), false).Length > 0)
            .ToArray(); //Get all methods with the type of attribute you are looking for

        foreach (var method in allMehtods)
        {
            method.Invoke(myClassObj, null); //Invoke method

        }

        
    }
```

Comment: This offers little more than what I've posted but the IsWidow takes a parameter - how do you handle that?  This to me represents a significant flaw in what the OP seems to be doing

Comment: Let me edit my answer. Just give me a couple of minutes :)

Comment: but how do you know to pass the method "Some Text"?  IsWidow takes a Guid for example.  I have to say I don't really know what your answer has that mine does not, nor whether either of our answers really answer the question

Comment: @TimRutter Hey tim. First of all my answer handles the case of a custom attribute with a value in it. And to answer your question on how do I know what to pass wo that method: You could create some custom attributes that give you some information on what to pass e.g [ErrorMessageText(TEXT)]. But I think the easiest way is: If you are looking for a method you also know what this method needs to work otherwise how do you know the method you are looking for?. You might not know the name of the it but you know what it does othe.w you couldn't search for it because you wouldn't know that it exists.

Comment: @TimRutter I was looking at your answer and you are right, both are similar. I really understand your point. Thank you for your opinion, I will think about it and contact you if I get something out

Comment: @TimRutter Tim, I found something that might help you with your question. Are you still interested?

Comment: yes you could update your answer to help anyone who comes across this question, i don't think the OP can create custom attributes as he says its generated.  Again its really not clear what he's trying to do, so it may be a bit pointless doing any more

Comment: thanks for spending the time.  as I say, its not clear what the OP needs to do so may not be worth updating further.  You are iterating through all the parameters and then putting the names of them in a switch - so now you need to know all the names of all the parameters in all the methods in your DoWork method.  Thats not really a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using my powers of deduction I think you might want to call the method based on the CodeName attribute.  In which case you can use reflection to get the attributes.

The method below allows you to call a method that has an attribute that matches the CodeName that you want.  `pars` is an optional list of parameters that need to be passed to the method, this is a flaw in the plan really because you will need to know the signature of the method to know what parameters to pass in.

```
 object? CallMethod(object target, string codeName, params object[] pars)
    {
        foreach (var m in target.GetType().GetMethods())
        {
            var att = m.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<CodeNameAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (att != null)
            {
                if (att.Name == codeName)
                {
                    return m.Invoke(target, pars);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

i'm not absolutely sure what you are trying to achieve, so its hard to know whether the above function is really of any use

Comment: for example How can I get the attribute code name in this example.I don't know very much about reflection .

Comment: the only way is through reflection.  What are you trying to achieve?  I have  a hunch you're going about this the wrong way

Comment: For example I have a code like `code1` I want to use this code to call IsWidow() function.How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need to update your question to be more clear.  What you have written there doesn't explain anything.  what is "code1"?

Comment: @amirkian I think i know what you mean, see my edit

Comment: could you explain what you have done and what is `params object[] pars`>?